# SQL JOIN с подзапросом

Tags: sql, join

Пишу свою статистику для сайта. Есть таблица, в которой собирается вся статистика посещений. Пишется каждый клик по каждой странице. У пользователя вешается кука с user_id и по ней записываются время посещения и прочие данные. Поля таблицы user_id,date_added,ip,url,referer. Я решил считать, что если между кликами прошло больше часа, то будем считать это отдельным "визитом". Придумался вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT s.*, 
 (SELECT   TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, l.date_added, s.date_added ) 
 FROM  stat l WHERE l.`user_id` = '012345' AND l.user_id = s.user_id  AND l.date_added< s.date_added ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 1 ) as lst 
FROM stat s
WHERE s.`user_id` = '012345' HAVING (lst > 1 OR lst IS NULL)
ORDER BY date_added ASC
```

В запросе идея такая - для каждой строки смотрю время предыдущего посещения и если прошло больше часа или оно NULL (т.е. самое первое посещение) то считаю это новым визитом.

Для одного пользователя вроде получилось.

Вопрос как такой запрос приджойнить по user_id к еще одной таблице посетителей (поля user_id, ФИО, емейл и т.д)  чтобы можно было отбирать "всех пользователей у которых визитов больше 3" или "всех у кого имя начинается на А" или по любым  другим условиям. 
Может я просто с этим запросом перемудрил и все решается легче?

Comment: Укажите DBMS, включая версию. Для заданного вопроса это более чем важно.

Comment: Используется mySql 5.6.17

Answer (score 1):

Решим задачу вывода "визитов":

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM stat t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM stat t2
                  WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, t1.date_added, t2.date_added) = 0)
```

С полученной выборкой уже делай что хочешь - группируй, считай, фильтруй...

Comment: Не-а. Не сработал запрос. На вскидку не могу понять почему, но выдает NULL. Собственно вопрос я решил, ниже описал как. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это часть кода в подзапросе

```
WHERE l.`user_id` = '012345' AND l.user_id = s.user_id
```

легко сокращается до

```
WHERE l.user_id = s.user_id
```

После чего WHERE user_id остается только в одном месте запроса и прекрасно джойнится куда надо. 
Заработался я к вечеру вчера :/